# Authenticating Service Principle of Another company

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I have a python script running in company-A. It users service priniciple SPN-A created in active directory company-A in python SDK .(client_id,client_secret,tenent_id and subscription_id).

Script is simply reading tags of VM,disks,vnets etc (using reader role assigned to SPN-A)

Now i want to  use the same SPN-A to connect to other company-B and run the same script. How can i achieve this ?What changes I need to perform in company-B to enable SPN-A to read tags of VM,disks,vnets etc?

I expect SPN-A of company-A to read tags of VM,disks,vnets of company-B.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for cross tenant resource access is available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-tenant-access-overview